# Jquery data json not showing in Html [Laravel]

Tags: jquery, laravel

I want to get json data, But when the row in html code it's now showing anything
**Html Code**

```
       <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>No</th>
            <th>Waktu</th>
        </tr>
       </thead>
       <tbody id="bodyData">
       </tbody>  
    </table>
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        var url = "{{URL('userData')}}";
        $.ajax({
            url: "mulai/getUserData",
            type: "GET",
            data:{ 
                _token:'{{csrf_token()}}'
            },
            cache: false,
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function(dataResult){
                console.log(dataResult);
                var resultData = dataResult.data;
                var bodyData = '';
                var i=1;
                $.each(resultData,function(row){
                    bodyData+="<tr>"
                    bodyData+="<td>"+ i++ +"</td>"
                    "<td>"+row.waktu+"</td>"
                    ;
                    bodyData+="</tr>";
                    
                })
                $("#bodyData").append(bodyData);
            }
        });    
});
</script>
```

**Result Data with URL Method GET mulai/getUserData**

```
{"data":[{"id":4,"namakelas":"Percobaan","waktu":"1","created_at":"2020-08-27T03:52:36.000000Z","updated_at":"2020-08-27T03:52:36.000000Z"}]}
```

But when row in html code it's now showing anything

Comment: It might be showing you `undefined` .Instead Try like this -> `resultData[row].waktu` and see if that works .

Comment: you can see your json in json formatter from online tool. then take decision

Comment: Deleted my answer since i have no idea what what OP wants further. Provided a working solution below and OP has some question on how to get data from the Database which does not make sense to what this question is about.

Comment: I mean showing data with json from my database , i using  
`$.ajax({
            url: "mulai/getUserData",`
But not showing anything , i'm learning from this link https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/how-to-show-data-with-ajax